# How to extract specific data from two different json object

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to extract all department that exists in the departments array and not exists in the dep_log. Also I want to extract all the departments that have delete=1.

Note: if two departments have same id with deleted=1, I want to retrieve only the latest one without duplication.

I tried this way but I got wrong results:

```js
var departments = [{
  "department_id": "1",
  "name": "sales"
}, {
  "department_id": "2",
  "name": "marketing"
}, {
  "department_id": "3",
  "name": "operation"
}];

var dep_logs = [{
  "department_id": "2",
  "creation_date": "2023-05-22 15:47:58",
  "created_by": "1",
  "deleted": "0"
}, {
  "department_id": "2",
  "creation_date": "2023-05-22 15:46:56",
  "created_by": "1",
  "deleted": "1"
}, {
  "department_id": "3",
  "creation_date": "2023-05-13 17:59:27",
  "created_by": "1",
  "deleted": "0"
}, {
  "department_id": "2",
  "creation_date": "2023-05-13 17:59:11",
  "created_by": "1",
  "deleted": "1"
}, {
  "department_id": "1",
  "creation_date": "2023-05-13 09:46:25",
  "created_by": "1",
  "deleted": "0"
}];

var finalList = []
var finalMapDeletedDepartment = []
var idSet = new Set();

dep_logs.forEach(item => {
  idSet.add(item.department_id);

  if (item.deleted === 1) {
    if (finalMapDeletedDepartment.has(item.department_id)) {
      var itemValue = finalMapDeletedDepartment.get(item.department_id);
      if (itemValue.creation_date < item.creation_date) {
        finalMapDeletedDepartment.set(item.department_id, item);
      }
    } else {
      finalMapDeletedDepartment.set(item.department_id, item);
    }
  }
});

departments.forEach(item => {
  if (!idSet.has(item.id)) {
    finalList.push(item)
  }
});
console.log(idSet);

console.log(finalMapDeletedDepartment.values());

console.log(finalList);
```

The results should be stored in new array.

Comment: You don't have any duplicate department IDs in your sample data, so it's hard to see how that part of the requirement applies.

Comment: @Barmar mean in dep_log

Comment: `item.deleted === 1` will never be true. `item.deleted` is a string, `1` is a number, and you're using strict equality.

Comment: How would you get duplicates in the result, since you're iterating over `departments`, which doesn't have any duplicates?

Comment: @Barmar I tried also with two quotations and not working

Comment: `finalMapDeletedDepartment.has()` and `finalMapDeletedDepartment.set()` can never work. `finalMapDeletedDepartment` is an array, not a Set.

Comment: @BarmarI don't get duplicate number but I get wrong results

Comment: I'm asking about this sentence in the requirements "I want to retrieve only the latest one without duplication."

Comment: @Barmar department that have deleted=0 should never store in the results, I need only departments not exists in the dep_log and that have deleted=1 without duplication

Comment: @Barmar I meant the department that have newest creation date if they save same id

Comment: Typo: `item.id` should be `item.department_id`.

Comment: You're never using `finalMapDeletedDepartment` in the `departments.forEach()` loop.

Comment: @Barmar please if you know the answers try to help me

Comment: I don't know the answer. All I see are obvious typos. `finalMapDeletedDepartment` should be a `new Map()`, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will do the job :

**To get not-logged departments:**

```
function get_not_logged_deps() {
  // first get a list of id of logged departments
  const logged_deps_ids = dep_logs.map((l) => l.department_id);

  // then filter only departments whose id does not exists in the list
  return departments.filter((d) =>   !logged_deps_ids.includes(d.department_id));
}
```

**To get deleted departments (not duplicate and the most recent one):**

```
function get_deleted_deps() {
  const deleted_deps_ids = []; 

  // first sort by date desc
  // then in case of duplication only push the first one (created last) and ignore the next ones (older logs)
  return dep_logs
      .sort((a, b) => (a.creation_date < b.creation_date ? 1 : -1))
      .filter((l) => {
            if (
                l.deleted === "1" &&
                deleted_deps_ids.indexOf(l.department_id) === -1
             ) {
                deleted_deps_ids.push(l.department_id);
                return true;
               }
      });
}
```

```js
var departments = [
  {
    department_id: "1",
    name: "sales",
  },
  {
    department_id: "2",
    name: "marketing",
  },
  {
    department_id: "3",
    name: "operation",
  },
];

var dep_logs = [
  {
    department_id: "2",
    creation_date: "2023-05-22 15:47:58",
    created_by: "1",
    deleted: "0",
  },
  {
    department_id: "3",
    creation_date: "2023-05-13 17:59:27",
    created_by: "1",
    deleted: "0",
  },
  {
    department_id: "2",
    creation_date: "2023-05-13 17:59:11",
    created_by: "1",
    deleted: "1",
  },
  {
    department_id: "3",
    creation_date: "2023-05-13 09:46:25",
    created_by: "1",
    deleted: "0",
  },
  {
    department_id: "2",
    creation_date: "2023-05-22 15:46:56",
    created_by: "1",
    deleted: "1",
  },
];

function get_not_logged_deps() {
  const logged_deps_ids = dep_logs.map((l) => l.department_id);

  return departments.filter((d) => !logged_deps_ids.includes(d.department_id));
}

function get_deleted_deps() {
  const deleted_deps_ids = [];

  return dep_logs
    .sort((a, b) => (a.creation_date < b.creation_date ? 1 : -1))
    .filter((l) => {
      if (
        l.deleted === "1" &&
        deleted_deps_ids.indexOf(l.department_id) === -1
      ) {
        deleted_deps_ids.push(l.department_id);
        return true;
      }
    });
}

console.log(get_not_logged_deps());
console.log(get_deleted_deps());
```